# Remove a node from the newly opened window jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to use the following code to open a new window.

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
     var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
     $(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
     return false;
});
```

The problem I'm having is the new window does open with the output required but the line where I'm using `$(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();` isn't working i.e. the `.top-fixed-nav` doesn't remove. I've tried binding it to the `ready` event as well

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
       var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
    $(w).ready(function(){
        $(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

but that didn't work either. Can anyone please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

Have tried this:

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
       var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
//        $(w.document).ready(function(){
// and    $(w.document).load(function(){
        $(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Both of these didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show us related html of window you opening?

Comment: Are the windows on the same domain?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sorry! what do you mean by that?

Comment: @KamranAhmed Is the second page you're loading on the same [top level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) as the opening page? For example - they are if they're both on `http://stackoverflow.com` but it's not if one is on `http://google.com` and the other is on `http://www.wikipedia.org` .

Comment: +1 Good point Benjamin. We were assuming that `this.href` was pointing to the same domain!

Comment: Both are on the `localhost`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
    var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
    $(w).on("load", function(){
        $(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

try this as onload method works on window not document.

Answer (score 2):

Try binding to load instead of ready:

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
    var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
    $(w.document).on("load", function(){
        $(w.document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

After some fiddling arround got this:

```
$("#printBtn").on("click", function () {
    var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
    var callInterval = setInterval(childCall, 100);
    function childCall(){
        if (typeof w.jQuery !== "undefined") {
            //w.jQuery(document.body).children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
            w.jQuery(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
            if(typeof callInterval !== "undefined")
                window.clearInterval(callInterval);
        }

    };
    return false;
});
```

Give it a try and let us know if it works:D

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried to use an alert in side the `on load` as well but that `alert` wasn't called either.

Comment: `load` is deprecated since version 1.8

Comment: You are right .load is deprecated but if you look closely I'm using on("load" ...., this is not deprecated :D

Comment: Good one @ValiD but just a +1 for you, unfortunately, I have already chosen an answer ;)

Comment: OK, did you test @Adnan Ahmed 's solution in IE becasue I can not get it to work and I'm wondering if it's something wrong with my system :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var w = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
w.document.$('body').children(".top-fixed-nav").remove();
```

Alternatively:

```
$(".top-fixed-nav", w.document.body).remove();
```

**Note**: you may have to introduce a delay to allow the window to be loaded.

```
setTimeout('$(".top-fixed-nav", w.document.body).remove()', 5000);
```

Comment: First one is not even possible

`TypeError: Object [object HTMLDocument] has no method '$'`

Let me try the second one.

Comment: Yep that is being loaded, see`window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");` The window does take the time to load as that taken by the original window

Comment: Ya, you may have to introduce a delay.

Comment: But in any case, you have to! Unless the child window has its DOM loaded, how can you manipulate it?